# Django Admin: multi-table inheritance child model with many-to-many through inline fails with "Please correct the error below"

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I'm not sure if this is a bug, limitation or error on my part, but I would like to get feedback on if there is a solution or work around to this issue...

In Django Admin, I have created a many-to-many inline based on a 'through' model `ReleaseCardCount`. The inline is linked to a parent class `Card` which is used for numerous child models. In Django Admin, I am only interested in configuring the child classes of `Card`, for example, `ActionCard`.

If I configure Django Admin for the parent `Card` model and `ReleaseCardCount` inline, I am able to add, remove and modify parent and inline objects without issue. If I configure the same set up for a child object of card, for example `ActionCard`, I can add inline objects if there are none or delete all inline objects, but I am unable to modify `ActionCard` or an inline object if an inline exists. If an inline object is present and I attempt to modify and save any data I get a "Please correct the error below" message, with no error present.

I've minimised the code needed to recreate the issue to the following...

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Release2(models.Model):
    release_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    release_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.release_name

class Card2(models.Model):
    card_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True) 
    card_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    release_card_count = models.ManyToManyField( Release2, through='ReleaseCardCount2',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.card_name

class ReleaseCardCount2(models.Model):
    rcc_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    rcc_release = models.ForeignKey(Release2, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rcc_card = models.ForeignKey(Card2, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rcc_count = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1, null=True, blank=True)

class ActionCard2(Card2):
    action_card_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    action_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.card_name
```

admin.py:

```
from .models import (Release2, Card2, ReleaseCardCount2, ActionCard2)

class ReleaseCardCount2InLine(admin.TabularInline):
    model = ReleaseCardCount2
    extra = 1

class Card2Admin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (ReleaseCardCount2InLine,)
    model = Card2

class ActionCard2Admin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (ReleaseCardCount2InLine,)
    model = ActionCard2

admin.site.register(Release2)
admin.site.register(Card2, Card2Admin)
admin.site.register(ActionCard2, ActionCard2Admin)
```

Of interest, in my troubleshooting, I dropped and recreated the database in a dev environment. I found that one of the child models that was not working before, suddenly began to work. I suspect, that it worked due to being the first child model I configured Django Admin for with the inline. To recreate the issue with the above code, you may need try running it *FIRST* on the parent `Card` model. Once you have added, saved then modified and saved an inline object on `Card`, you can try it on `ActionCard`.

Relevant environment info:

- Django - 2.0.6
- Python - 3.6.4
- PostgreSQL - 10.4